# comparison of de Rham cohomology and etale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I have a basic question concerning comparison of different cohomology theories. Let $X$ be a projective smooth (or just proper smooth) variety over a separably closed field $k$ of characteristic $p,$ which is not liftable to characteristic zero. 
Is there any relation between the de Rham cohomology $H^n(X,\Omega^{\bullet}_X)$ and the $\ell$-adic cohomology? For example, do they have the same dimension (over $k$ and $Q_l$ resp.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, that these two spaces need not have the same vector space dimension. Grothendieck here cites an example of Serre in a footnote on the last page; unfortunately, I don't have access to Serre's original paper at the moment.

[http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1966_*29*_95_0](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1966__29__95_0)

Comment: I don't know how my link became mangled, but ignore the junk string before http.

Comment: I believe there's supposed to be a double underscore surrounding 29 in the link (which I guess is why it appears italicized). (The paper is "On the de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties"). Here's a fixed version: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=PMIHES_1966__29__95_0

Comment: The most classical type examples are non-ordinary Enriques surfaces in characteristic 2.

Answer (score 32):

Often, yes. What always has the same dimension as $H^n_{et}(X,Q_l)$ is the rational crystalline cohomology $H^n_{cr}(X)\otimes K$ with coefficients in the fraction field $K$ of the Witt vectors $W$ of $k$. $H^n_{cr}(X)$ itself will have coefficients in $W$, and of course, have rank equal to the dimension of  $H^n_{cr}(X)\otimes K$. But it might have torsion in general. On the other hand, there is an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow H^n_{cr}(X)\otimes_W k\rightarrow H^n(X,\Omega_X^{\cdot})\rightarrow H^{n+1}_{cr}(X)[p]\rightarrow 0$$
as in the universal coefficient theorem. This is because crystalline cohomology can be taken with any of the torsion coefficients $W/p^n$, and when you take it with coefficients in $W/p=k$, you get exactly De Rham cohomology. (One of the most important things to learn at the beginning about crystalline cohomology with $W/p^n$ coefficients  is that it can be computed using the divided power De Rham complex associated to a smooth embedding over $W/p^n$, which reduces to the De Rham complex of $X$ itself when the coefficients are $W/p$.)

So you will get the same dimensions you want if enough of crystalline cohomology is torsion-free. All this is explained in introductory books, such as the one by Berthelot and Ogus, except the comparison with \'etale cohomology. That is perhaps explained in a paper by Katz and Messing from the 70's.

Comment: If one also wants the proper case one needs to use de Jong's alterations on top of Katz-Messing.